# Set $S = \{(b_1, b_2, b_3, ...) : b_i = \pm i! \mbox{ for all } i\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I'm attempting to do a problem involving free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules, and ran upon this description of a particular, well, I *think* it's supposed to be a $\mathbb{Z}$-module: $S = \{(b_1, b_2, b_3, ...) : b_i = \pm i! \mbox{ for all } i\}$.

This definition confuses me. In particular, I read $\pm i!$ as "plus or minus i factorial", and since factorial isn't usually defined for negative numbers (I don't think the gamma function is in play here), I read the minus side as "-(i!)". But $b_i$ is only one number, right? So is it the positive or negative one? Or am I misreading what "!" means in this context?

Edit, for better context:
The question I'm working on is supposed to be a bunch of steps to show that a direct product of a free module need not be free. S might not be a module, but it has to at least be a set; I'm supposed to prove that S is uncountable and that it has some element that another set, which is a module, doesn't have. But I'm stuck at the definition of S; the symbols used in the definition don't make sense to me as they are written.

Comment: It might not be a module..the question doesn't seem to require it to be, I think. But my problem is understanding the way it's defined in the first place.

Comment: $S$ has $(1,2,6,\dots)$ and $(-1,2,6,\dots)$ and $(1,-2,6,\dots)$ and $(-1,-2,6,\dots)$ and so on.

Comment: Thanks, Gerry. Sometimes the obvious escapes me for some reason. I think I was for some reason reading the bi's as elements of s instead of the whole collection (b1, b2, ...) as an element.